# Wordpress 3 insert image to Custom Post Type item

Tags: wordpress

I have a Custom Post Type and I am going to customize it to show a list of some products with images. I have all text fields working fine but I need also an image to be attached to each item. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each post is a single item, you can add post thumbnail support in your theme, which allows users to either browse for or upload an image and assign it to the post.

`add_theme_support('post-thumbnails')`

You'll also need to add `thumbnail` to your `supports` array when you register your custom post type.

```
register_post_type('product', array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'content', 'thumbnail')
))
```

You can then retrieve the thumbnail in your theme files using `get_post_thumbnail()`. Check out the other post thumbnail functions in `wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php`.